# How do you see it (Gm7/Bb?) and what functions would this chord have?

Tags: harmony

The four last chord in this hymn ( Hela världen fröjdes Herran) is a 6-2-5-1 progression. I have written that we have Dm-Gm/Bb-C-F. This is wrong. I now see it as Gm7/Bb.
How do you see it and what functions would this chord have?

[image]

Comment: I'd call it a first inversion Gm7.

Answer (score 1):

Can't see the Key signature but will assume a Bb is in it since you mention it in the question, and the line ends on F (which you are calling I).  Also, safe bet that the bottom staff is Bass clef.

The third to last chord is clearly (Bb, F, D, G), and a G-7 chord is (G, Bb, D, F).
This can also be seen as a Bb6 chord (Bb, D, F, G) which is the IV of the key.  Not sure if the tie on F changes the character of the chord from a theory point of view.

Answer (score 1):

With B♭, F D and G, it could be Gm7/B♭, or B♭6. Either will suffice, although the cycle of fourths would make the last four chords Dm, Gm, C, F - a common enough sequence. Calling it Gm would make it a sort of v/V, which isn't a particularly strong pre-dominant. All this on the assumption the key sig. is one flat.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming key signature of one flat.

Chord symbols:

`Dm Gm7/Bb C F`

Roman numeral analysis:

`vi ii6/5 V I`

The `Gm7/Bb`/`ii6/5` is functionally a *pre-dominant*. Technically is a supertonic seventh chord, but it often is thought of a kind of sub-dominant, because if contains the complete sub-dominant (F:IV) chord `Bb D F`.

Also, from a functional perspective the *cadence* is super important. The essence of the cadence is the `^4 ^5 ^1` of the bass with `^2 ^1` above.

> I have written that we have Dm-Gm/Bb-C-F. This is wrong. I now see it as Gm7/Bb.

At first I didn't really understand your question, but now I think I see.

The tie on the `F3` between `vi ii6/5` forms the seventh of the `ii` chord which is a dissonance that then resolves down by step to `E3`.

I think your question is should that `F3` be regarded as the seventh of a proper seventh chord or *passing motion* between `F3` and `E3`?

`V7` and `ii7` are very common seventh chords. I would regard it as a proper seventh chord.

If it were a less common seventh chord, like `IM7`, I would probably expect the seventh to be better explained as a non-chord tone. But `V7` and `ii7` are common enough to stand as proper seventh chords.